# The probability of a hand being void in zero suits

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I'm finding the probability that a 5 card hand is void in at least one suit, event B. I've approached the problem by calculating the probability of the complement.

$$P(B) = 1 -P(B^c)$$

where the solution is given by

$$P(B)=1-\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}^3}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

However, I don't understand the logical used regarding the numerator, and would like someone to break it down for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should say that you are considering five card hands.  $B^c$ is the chance that all four suits are represented.  As there are only five cards, you must have two of one suit and one of each other.  So $4 \choose 1$ is the number of ways to select the suit with two cards, $13 \choose 2$ selects the cards from that suit, and each $13 \choose 1$ selects the card from one other suit.

Comment: Ah, I understand now - thanks! Also, is their an implicit $\binom{4}{4}$ for every $\binom{13}{1}$?

Comment: I don't think so.  We have chosen the suit with two cards, so now the other three suits, which have one card each, are determined.  You could say there is an implicit $3 \choose 3$ to select the one card suits.